# SAS Raw data importing

Tags: sas

I want to import a raw dataset in SAS whose first column starts with "C".But 
 there is something wrong with my code as ERROR keeps popping up in log window:-

Can anybody help me realise it??

**Sample dataset:=**

```
H 1095 NJ 06DEC84
C 01DEC11 $45.0
C 01AUG11 $37.5
H 1096 CA 01SEP83
```

**My code : -**

```
  Filename hca2 'C:\Users\Desktop\SAS\datasets\HCA_file.txt';                                                                             
    Data assign8.hca2;                                                                                                                      
    Infile hca2;                                                                                                                            

    Input@1 FC $1.;                                                                                                                       

    If FC = 'C' then                                                                                                                        
    Input @3 DOB @11 Transaction_Value ;                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                             Run;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use proc import? http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1qn5sclnu2l9dn1w61ifw8wqhts.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: No sir @pinegulf! I only had to import the transaction rows and not headers ...i don't know if proc import will work!

Answer (score 2):

The error (which would have been good to add to the question) is likely from the input of DOB without an associated informat.  The following may help.

```
 attrib dob informat=date9. format=date9.;
```

informat is for processing input and format is for output.

A simple `INPUT` statement will read in some data and immediately skip to the next line.

When processing a single line of data with multiple input statements, the earlier input statements should use a trailing @ symbol to indicate 'held-input' and causes the input processor to not immediately proceed to the next line.  Instead the 'active position' of the input processor will remain in the same line at the last position used for input.

Changing the code as follows will force the input processor to remain on the same line.

```
  input @1 FC $1. @;
```

Note: The input processor will skip to the next line when the next implicit data step iteration occurs.  This means when your `if` fails the next iteration in the data step will be reading from the next line in the file.

Input can be held across implicit iterations by using two @ symbols (`input .... @@;`)